# How to send message proactively in Rails( api-only ) Apps using ActionCable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

## Description

### The project structure :

- A Vue based FE project .
- A Rails( api-only ) project for backend . ruby263@rails517

### The requirements :

1. FE open a websocket link , subscribe with params `{ weigh_device_id : 1}` .
2. BE confirm subscribtion .
3. BE find device by weigh_device_id .
4. When client calling "WeighDevice#sync_reading" , BE send device reading immediately .
5. When Device reading updated , BE send fresh device reading proactively .

### The 'weighDevice' Model

```
weighDevice : {
    id: integer,
    reading: integer
}
```

## What I have Done

### Rails

```rb
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount ActionCable.server => '/ws'
end

# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
# I don't need Authorization
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base

    def connect
    end

  end
end

# app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
# I don't need Authorization
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base

  end
end

# app/channels/weigh_device_channel.rb
class WeighDeviceChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    # next line code is for the requirement 4th .
    stream_from "WeighDeviceChannel"
    # next line code is for the requirement 5th . 
    # that's mean I want to broadcast message out of this Channel class .
    # but I don't know how to do that ... so , here is a trial ...
    # I'm not finding device by id ,directly using the last .
    stream_for WeighDevice.last
  end

  def unsubscribed

  end

  def sync_reading(args)
    # this solve the requirement 4th .
    # the client received the reading immediately .
    ActionCable.server.broadcast('WeighDeviceChannel', {reading: 0})
  end
end

# I didn't write 'after_commit' in WeighDeviceModel .
# I just make a trial in rails console .
# rails c
ActionCable.server.broadcast_to('WeighDeviceChannel', {reading: 0});
# nothing happened, client didn't receive anything but 'ping' .
# then I tried this 
ActionCable.server.broadcast_to(WeighDeviceChannel.last, {reading: 0});
# nothing happened either, client didn't receive anything but 'ping' .
```

### Javascript

```js
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/ws/');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
    "command":"subscribe",
    "identifier": JSON.stringify({channel: 'WeighDeviceChannel'});
});

let sent = false;

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
   const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
   console.log(data); // checking what the server say here .
   if(data.type = 'confirm_subscription' && !sent){
       socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                "command":"message",
                "identifier": JSON.stringify({channel: 'WeighDeviceChannel'}),
                "data":JSON.stringify({message:'hello-server',
                                       action:'sync_reading'})
       }));
       sent = true;
    }
});
```

So, here are the questions .

1. What's difference between `broadcast_to` and `broadcast` ?
2. `broadcast_to` and `broadcast` accept different params and available in different field . that is , I can only use `broadcast` in `WeighDeviceChannel#action` but not out of it . And I can only use `broadcast_to` out of `WeighDeviceChannel#action` but not in it .
3. Why I cannot receive anything on client-side ? What's problem in my demo ?

Comment: What's FE or BE?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't described clearly . It's FrontEnd and BackEnd .

Answer (score 1):

I have understand what happened .

the `rails c` is not in the same thread with `rails server` . so nothing happened when i send a message in `rails c` . i move `ActionCable.server.broadcast_to(WeighDeviceChannel.last, {reading: 0});`  to a controller's action and every thing works .